# Scalable kmean++ numerical example

Tags: references, k-means

I need a numerical example for computing the scalable kmeans++, since I'm not specialist in statistics and I didn't understand the messy greek letters in the algorithm. Any text reference link will be great useful. 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you haven't yet, please check out https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour.  Could you add a reference to scalable k-means++?

Comment: Thank for welcoming Dr. Juho ... This my first question in this site. What does it mean by "on hold" . Can anybody else could see or answer my question ?